# How to find split where the split sums are close to each other?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, recursion, split

I have a list is

> test = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]

​and I would like to find split where the split sums are close to each other by number of splits = 3 that ​all possible combinations and select the split where the sum differences are smallest.

Comment: didn't understand anything out of it. Please clarify and give desired output or step wise example with the test case you have provided here.

Comment: Your question is not clear. I _think_ you want to split the list into 3 parts, each with roughly the same sum, eg `[[10,20,30,40,50], [60,70,80], [90,100]]`. Is that correct? Are you allowed to change the order of the items? If so, `[[10,20,30,40,80], [50,60,70], [90,100]]` would be a possible solution.

Comment: Do you have any example code where you've attempted this yet?

Comment: Yes. It's correct. And not allowed to change the order (:

Comment: SO is not a code-writing service.  Show what you've done if you want people to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This first script uses a double `for` loop to split the input list into all possible triplets of lists. For each triplet it calculates the sum of each list in the triplet, then creates a sorted list named `diffs` of the absolute differences of those sums. It saves a tuple consisting of `diffs` followed by the triplet into a list named `all_splits`. Finally, it sorts `all_splits`, and because each item in `all_splits` begins with `diffs` the saved tuples are sorted in order of their `diffs` from lowest to highest.

```
def split_list_test(lst):
    all_splits = []
    for i in range(1, len(lst) - 1):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(lst)):
            splits = [lst[:i], lst[i:j], lst[j:]]
            a, b, c = map(sum, splits)
            diffs = sorted((abs(c-a), abs(c-b), abs(b-a)), reverse=True)
            all_splits.append((diffs, splits))
    all_splits.sort()
    return all_splits

test = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]

for row in split_list_test(test):
    print(row)
```

**output**

```
([60, 40, 20], [[10, 20, 30, 40, 50], [60, 70, 80], [90, 100]])
([60, 40, 20], [[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60], [70, 80], [90, 100]])
([140, 110, 30], [[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60], [70, 80, 90], [100]])
([140, 120, 20], [[10, 20, 30, 40, 50], [60, 70], [80, 90, 100]])
([160, 90, 70], [[10, 20, 30, 40], [50, 60, 70, 80], [90, 100]])
([170, 90, 80], [[10, 20, 30, 40], [50, 60, 70], [80, 90, 100]])
([180, 110, 70], [[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70], [80, 90], [100]])
([200, 110, 90], [[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70], [80], [90, 100]])
([200, 140, 60], [[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60], [70], [80, 90, 100]])
([200, 150, 50], [[10, 20, 30, 40, 50], [60, 70, 80, 90], [100]])
([210, 160, 50], [[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60, 70], [80, 90, 100]])
([240, 130, 110], [[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60, 70, 80], [90, 100]])
([240, 220, 20], [[10, 20], [30, 40, 50, 60, 70], [80, 90, 100]])
([240, 230, 10], [[10, 20, 30, 40], [50, 60], [70, 80, 90, 100]])
([250, 250, 0], [[10, 20, 30, 40], [50, 60, 70, 80, 90], [100]])
([260, 260, 0], [[10], [20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70], [80, 90, 100]])
([270, 260, 10], [[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80], [90], [100]])
([280, 190, 90], [[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60], [70, 80, 90, 100]])
([280, 190, 90], [[10, 20, 30, 40, 50], [60], [70, 80, 90, 100]])
([300, 160, 140], [[10, 20], [30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80], [90, 100]])
([310, 160, 150], [[10, 20], [30, 40, 50, 60], [70, 80, 90, 100]])
([330, 190, 140], [[10], [20, 30, 40, 50, 60], [70, 80, 90, 100]])
([330, 290, 40], [[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90], [100]])
([340, 180, 160], [[10], [20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80], [90, 100]])
([340, 310, 30], [[10, 20, 30], [40, 50], [60, 70, 80, 90, 100]])
([350, 300, 50], [[10, 20, 30, 40], [50], [60, 70, 80, 90, 100]])
([370, 280, 90], [[10, 20], [30, 40, 50], [60, 70, 80, 90, 100]])
([390, 260, 130], [[10], [20, 30, 40, 50], [60, 70, 80, 90, 100]])
([390, 320, 70], [[10, 20], [30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90], [100]])
([410, 390, 20], [[10, 20, 30], [40], [50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]])
([420, 380, 40], [[10, 20], [30, 40], [50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]])
([430, 340, 90], [[10], [20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90], [100]])
([440, 360, 80], [[10], [20, 30, 40], [50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]])
([460, 460, 0], [[10, 20], [30], [40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]])
([480, 440, 40], [[10], [20, 30], [40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]])
([510, 500, 10], [[10], [20], [30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]])
```

---

The next script is a little more compact, and it only returns a single solution. It uses a different rule to decide on the minimal split. If `(a, b, c)` are the sums of the lists in a triplet, sorted from lowest to highest, then the absolute differences of those sums are `c-a`, `c-b`, and `b-a`. The sum of the differences is `c-a + c-b + b-a` which is equal to `2*(c-a)`, so we can find the minimal split (using this rule) by looking for the split with the minimal value of `c-a`.

```
def keyfunc(seq):
    sums = sorted(sum(u) for u in seq)
    return sums[2] - sums[0]

def split_list(lst):
    gen = ([lst[:i], lst[i:j], lst[j:]]
        for i in range(1, len(lst) - 1)
            for j in range(i + 1, len(lst)))
    return min(gen, key=keyfunc)

test = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
print(split_list(test))
```

**output**

```
[[10, 20, 30, 40, 50], [60, 70, 80], [90, 100]]
```

As you can see, for this `test` list this version gives the same solution as one of the minimal solutions found above.